# Doesn't (didn't) Scala have automatically generated setters?

Tags: scala

Google and my failing memory are both giving me hints that it does, but every attempt is coming up dry.

```
class Y {
    var y = 0
}
var m = new Y()
m.y_(3)

error: value y_ is not a member of Y
```

Please tell me I am doing something wrong.   (Also: please tell me *what it is* I am doing wrong.)

**EDIT**

The thing I am not doing wrong, or at least not the only thing I am doing wrong, is the way I am invoking the setter.  The following things also fail, all with the same error message:

```
m.y_ // should be a function valued expression
m.y_ = (3) // suggested by Google and by Mchl
f(m.y_) // where f takes Int => Unit as an argument
f(m.y)  // complains that I am passing in Int not a function
```

I am doing this all through SimplyScala, because I'm too lazy and impatient to set up Scala on my tiny home machine.  Hope it isn't that...

**And the winner is ...**

Fabian, who pointed out that I can't have a space between the _ and the =.  I thought out why this should be and then it occurred to me:

> The name of the setter for `y` is **not** `y_`, it is `y_=` !

Observe:

```
class Y {
     var y = 0
}
var m = new Y()
m.y_=(3)
m.y
res1: Int = 3
m.y_=
error: missing arguments for method y_= in class Y;
follow this method with `_` if you want to treat 
it as a partially applied function
       m.y_=
         ^
m.y_=_
res2: (Int) => Unit = 
def four(f : Int => Unit) = f(4) 
four(m.y_=)

m.y
res3: Int = 4
```

Another successful day on StackExchange.

Answer (score 8):

It does. They're just transparent.

`m.y = 3`

this actually accesses the `m.y` through a setter method.

Directly you can call `m.y_=(3)`

Comment: @Malvolio: This works for me in Scala 2.8.1. Not sure about other versins.

Comment: @Malvolio I think the problem is your blank in `m._ =`, it should be `m._=`, since the generated method is called `_=`, it is not using the assignment operator there.

Comment: @Fabian: Actually you're right. I don't know what I checked before (or how) but I retested it, and now it does make a difference ;)

Comment: @Mchl, as I now explain above, the full function name is `m.y_=`. Obviously, you can't put a space in the middle of a function name and expect it to still compile (except IIRC in Fortran).  That also explains the previously mysterious need for parentheses.

Comment: This only works for var correct?  if I try this with val I get an error.

Comment: `val` s are immutable, so you can't set them (except when defining them)

Comment: Thats what I figured. I would assume a feature like this could get some interesting errors if people don't understand what is going on.  Wouldn't setters in a language like Scala be a bad practice?

Comment: Not necessarily. Scala's paradigm is not 'purely' functional (and it never was advertised as such). You can do object oriented programming in Scala alongside functional.

Comment: @Mchl - Setters aren't a requirement for OO programming, and you can do OO programming with just immutable objects in a great many purely functional languages.  What you really meant to say was that Scala lets you do **imperative** programming alongside functional.

Comment: Kevin: you're probably right about that. I didn't mean setters are a requirement for OOP though. I meant that setters are violating immutability which is part of functional paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to judge from your examples, but it seems you were trying to pass the setter to a function that would then set a value on it. That is, looking at this:

```
f(m.y_) // where f takes Int => Unit as an argument
f(m.y)  // complains that I am passing in Int not a function
```

... suggests that there is a function f in which you want to set a value using the setter passed in.

*If that's what you were after*, then you can get it done by defining f like this:

```
def f(setter: Int => Unit) = setter(12)
```

... and then pass the setter on m like this:

```
f(m.y_=)
```

If m would be a fresh instance of Y, then this would result in y on m getting set to 12. In the snippet above, m.y_= is considered a function value. Once it is passed in, you can reference the function using the parameter name setter. Since it's a function, you can *apply* it simply by passing it the parameter it expects, which is a value of type Int.

Comment: yes, you are right in every particular (sorry I didn't make my examples more clear, but I was sorting through dozens of failed attempts).   I think the key observation, though, is that *the equal sign is an integral part of the function name*, not an ordinary assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Y(var y : Int = 0)
```

does the job.